# PHP and Curl not working for particular url

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I have a PHP script that uses Curl to get the number of tweets about our URLs; using this URL as an example:

http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://stackoverflow.com

Also, I'm using Phil Sturgeon's Curl library for CodeIgniter to perform the gets:
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl

When I run the script locally, the script runs fine. However, when I deploy it to our production environment, it breaks as soon as it tries to do a get on the above Twitter URL.

Here's the strange thing. I perform a similar like count retrieval for the same base URL from the Facebook Graph and it works on the production servers. See the example code below:

```
    $fb_get_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://stackoverflow.com";
    $twitter_get_url = "http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://stackoverflow.com";

    $fb_response_json = $this->curl->simple_get($fb_get_url, array(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true));
    $twitter_response_json = $this->curl->simple_get($twitter_get_url, array(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true));
```

simple_get works fine with $fb_get_url. However, I seem to be getting an error when I have Curl to do a get on $twitter_get_url. Unfortunately I can't tell you what the error is, as the connection keeps resetting right after the error. Also, to remind you, the same Twitter url on my own machine works fine; just when I deploy it to our servers it breaks.

Here's the strange thing. I tried ssh'ing into each of our servers and executing Curl from the command line with the same url and it worked. That proves to me that the call is not being blocked by the firewall or something.

So what I'm trying to figure out is this: why does running Curl from the CL work, but using Curl lib to do a get on the same URL seems to break? I don't think it's a bug in the CI Curl library I'm using, as I tried using the http_response function from http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php as well to test and it also seemingly threw an error.

As for the exact error; the only clue I have to the error is that the script takes a long while to fail and resets the connection; so I'm thinking it might be a timeout. I put the following code at the top of my controller to enable error display; but still didn't get any error message:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');
```

Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Frank

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but it looks like the way you are getting the twitter counts is not officially allowed. See https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5653

Comment: Have you tried building a CURL request without using the library?

Comment: Yes, I tried a direct PHP Curl request instead of using the library; had the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried checking $this->curl->error_code or $this->curl->error_string to get more information about what curl is doing?

Comment: You also might try flipping the two statements to see if the problem is the connection to twitter or with trying to do a second request.  Perhaps there's something in curl that needs cleaning up after the first get before you do another.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but is CURL support enabled in PHP? Make a phpinfo.php on your production server with `<?php phpinfo();` in it. Look for the `curl` section.

Comment: I think @Brendan is on it; the curl lib and the twitter url worked for me both locally and remotely. Also, +1 BenLee

Answer (score 0):

FYI,

Never figured out why the Facebook URL worked but the Twitter one didn't. We ended up working around the issue by using the Tweet button's onShare handler to call an AJAX service which increments the share count manually; therefore not needing to retrieve the share count directly from Twitter. It's not a perfect solution (it won't track retweets); but it's good enough for our needs.

Thanks anyway folks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Postman to see what's actually going on with the 'conversation'.  It's a REST client for Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

I've banged my head against a REST API more than a few times, and this has helped figure out what was going on...